# Deploying webapp to tomcat in Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, tomcat8

I want to deploy a webapp in Idea Ultimate with Gradle. Currently I can launch the tomcat 8.5.4 server but get a 404 when I try to browse to my context.

My build.gradle looks like:

```
group 'test'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'war'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.8.5'
}
```

In Idea I can build:war  ok
In Idea I can launch tomcat and get a 404
If I login to tomcat/manager (when tomcat has been launched from Idea) I do not see my app listed.

If I launch tomcat from the CLI I can see my app listed but when I click on it I get 404

There are no errors in the log windows for starting the server in Idea or building the war.

I believe my issue is to do with the way Idea launches tomcat and deploy's the war - but I am not sure what exactly.

Idea launches my browser to localhost:8080 and in the browser I get $END$

[image]

[image]

[image]

@crazycoder yes good point. I would expect the full path to access the webpage index1.jsp to be localhost:8080/poltest/form

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/index1.jsp").forward(request , response);
```

poltest being the name of the war and form being a url pattern

```
@WebServlet(name = "pol1310", urlPatterns = {"/form"})
```

I have shared the project zip which is only a few lines of code

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3rjaapNHpJJUWIwdnhXVlVlRDg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot of the IntelliJ tomcat configuration. Have you added a build artifact in the Deployment tab?

Comment: It's not clear how the artifact you are deploying is configured. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).